# Unit testing with an API involved

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rest

I'm a bit of newbie to unit testing, so go easy on me. I have some modules that query a RESTful API. I find that in each test suite I'm using a few lines of code to spin up a simple ExpressJS web server to mock up some routes that I can call from my tests. It gets old writing this could in every test suite. There's got to be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

BTW my code is all javascript running in NodeJS and the browser.

UPDATE: I'm not sure if I explained myself well in my original comment so here is some code example to help explain further.

Imagine that my test suite is testing a "Person" module:

```
describe("Person", function () {

    it("saves through REST API", function (done) {

        var person = new Person();

        //person gets posted to "/api/person/"
        person.save(function () {
            expect(person._id).to.be("id");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Normally I would create a small express server with the following route:

```
app.post("/api/person/*", function (req, res) { res.send(200, {data:0123}) });
```

But it stinks to have to do this for every test suite I write. If this can be accomplished using stubs or spies I would love to see an example of how. Or if I'm doing this all wrong please let me know what I can do different. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for stubbing/spy your ajax calls, check how many times they was executed, which params were passed etc. Check examples from the Sinon website for more info.

Comment: I read through the Sinon documentation closer and this looks like what I'm after, particularly stubs, fake XMLHttpRequest, or fake server should do the trick.

Comment: @skinneejoe related to fake server it very useful when you want to verify correct headers for your request. For example for CRUD operations. In other cases Sinon helps you to stub ajax execute, mock it with content which should be returned by your API and will be passed to callback for verification of right callback computing.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I use a "spy" object provided by [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to "spy" http calls => a mock.
Therefore, no need to call the real implementation, or configuring fake routes.
The goal is to ensure that the expected calls are made in certain circumstances and unexpected aren't.

Like @BuDen evokes, [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org) is perfect too for stubbing.